# how to create virtualenv with pypy?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pypy

running the following command

```bash
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/pypy pypy
```

exits with error like

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/pypy
New pypy executable in pypy/bin/pypy
debug: WARNING: Library path not found, using compiled-in sys.path.
debug: WARNING: 'sys.prefix' will not be set.
debug: WARNING: Make sure the pypy binary is kept inside its tree of files.
debug: WARNING: It is ok to create a symlink to it from somewhere else.
'import site' failed
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'prefix'
ERROR: The executable pypy/bin/pypy is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/Users/myname' (should be u'/Users/myname/pypy')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.1 (Mountain Lion) with CPython 2.7.3 and installed pypy 1.9 using Brew. virtualenv's version is 1.8.4.

Using pre-built pypy binary for Mac OS X downloaded directly from pypy's website doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on OS X and have the same versions of pypy and virtualenv as you (also installed pypy from homebrew)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This appears to be a regression in 1.8.4. While trying this out on my system everything worked fine with virtualenv 1.8.2, then I upgraded and now I get the same error as you.

Comment: I downgraded to 1.8.2 and it worked! Thanks!

Since this is an answer I think you should mention *how to* downgrade to 1.8.2 ```sudo pip install virtualenv==1.8.2```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on Windows using virtualenv 1.8.2. Also similar problems with 1.9 and 1.10. What worked for me was to run it once to make the directory, copy missing files, then run again to complete it.

```
virtualenv -p c:\bin\pypy\pypy.exe pypy
copy c:\bin\pypy\lib_pypy \virtualenvs\pypy
copy c:\bin\pypy\lib-python \virtualenvs\pypy
virtualenv -p c:\bin\pypy\pypy.exe pypy
```

Comment: I have confirmed this works on Windows7 for PyPy 2.2.0.  The only difference is <code>activate</code> is located in <code>bin</code> sub-directory rather than the <code>Scripts</code> sub-directory

Answer (score 1):

For `windows` this worked for me :

```py
python -m virtualenv -p <Your PYPY installed path\pypy3.exe> <venv_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution
Just use pypy3.exe instead of pypy.exe there are two .exe in downloaded folder

```
virtualenv -p C:/pypy3.7-v7.3.5-win64/pypy3.7-v7.3.5-win64/pypy3w.exe <folder_name>
```

By default python comes with venv. But venv has no -p
Install virtualenv using pip
Then use direct `virtualenv -p path/pypy3.exe <folder_name>`
no need to use `python -m`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this to work with Homebrew:

```
brew install pypy3
virtualenv -p /opt/homebrew/bin/pypy3 /<path-to-directory>/pypyenv
```

Answer (score -1):

With pypy-4.0.1 and virtualenv 14.0.3, out of the box I get an error:

```
Q:\>c:\pypy\bin\virtualenv -p c:\pypy\pypy.exe my_pypy_virtualenv
Already using interpreter c:\pypy\pypy.exe
New pypy executable in Q:\my_pypy_virtualenv\bin\pypy.exe
debug: OperationError:
debug:  operror-type: ImportError
debug:  operror-value: No module named UserDict
ERROR: The executable Q:\my_pypy_virtualenv\bin\pypy.exe is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'q:\\' (should be u'q:\\my_pypy_virtualenv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
Note: some Windows users have reported this error when they installed Python for "Only this user" or have multiple versions of Python installed. Copying the appropriate PythonXX.dll to the virtualenv Scripts/ directory may fix this problem.
```

Searching the original pypy install for `UserDict*`, I found `UserDict.py` in `lib-python\2.7` but in the virtualenv's `lib-python\2.7` there was only `userdict.py` and none of the capitalized `User` files. Following the example of the other solutions, I removed the virtualenv's `userdict.py` and copied the original `User*` files, and reran the `virtualenv` command, and it ran without error.